# Change the default redirection of croogo 1.3 (cakephp)

Tags: php, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-1.3, croogo

I am looking to change the default redirection of croogo 1.3 "loginRedirect"

default redirection is 'users / users /login'

my case is to redirect by role [admin][register][...]

My UsersController (action: login) :

```
public function login() {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', __d('croogo', 'Log in'));
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        Croogo::dispatchEvent('Controller.Users.beforeLogin', $this);
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {         
            switch($this->Auth->user('role_id')){
                case '1': // admin
                    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'admin_index','prefix'=>'admin','admin'=>true);
                    break;
                case '4': // manager
                    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'=>'managers','action'=>'index','prefix'=>'','manager'=>true);
                break; 
            }   
        } else {
            Croogo::dispatchEvent('Controller.Users.loginFailure', $this);
            $this->Session->setFlash($this->Auth->authError, 'default', array('class' => 'error'), 'auth');
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->loginAction);
        }

    }           
}
```

the problem in the redirection does not work...when I have the case manager '4 '.... it is always the redirection to /admin/index

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: in what way is the code you've got not working? please answer by editing the question.

Comment: yes i did that but it's not worked .... it always redirects me users / users /login

Comment: Normally when I have the case manager role '4 ' the redirection will be done to / managers / index....but this is not the case

Comment: @AD7six please it's ok for you ??

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

AuthComponent does not do the redirection.  You would need to call

```
$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
```

after your `switch` statement.

Secondly,

This does not look like Croogo 1.3. Events is only introduced in CakePHP 2.x, so this at least must be Croogo 1.4.x.